Trying to relate 2 arrays with different data types and be able to access their properties in Swift
I have the following problem.
I have 2 arrays using different data structures but with a single common attribute that appears in both arrays (serial number). I want to be able to dynamically link them so that:
a)  when I select an item in one list I am able to access one of the corresponding item’s properties (e.g. the item with the same serial number) from the other list - e.g the group.
b) be able to combine them into a live composite list - I have tried creating a new structure that contains both elements and then combing both arrays but this is not working
This is a simplified project that illustrates the issue.
struct Computer: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let name, id, serial: String
}


struct InventoryRecord: Hashable {
    let group, serial: String
}


var computers = [ Computer(name: "Mac1", id: "1", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"), Computer(name: "Mac2", id: "2", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaab") ]


var groupRecords = [ InventoryRecord(group: "London", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"), InventoryRecord(group: "NewYork", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaab") ]


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selection = Computer(name: "", id: "", serial: "")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List (computers, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { serial in
                    HStack {
                        Text(serial.name)
                        Text(serial.serial)
                    }
                }


            List (groupRecords, id: \.self) { serial in
                    HStack {
                        Text (String(describing: serial.group))
                        Text (String(describing: serial.serial))
                    }
                }
            
            Text("Selection is assigned to group:\(selection.name)")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

This is my attempt at combining the arrays:
var computers = [ Computer(name: "Mac1", id: "1", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"), Computer(name: "Mac2", id: "2", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaab") ]

var groupRecords = [ InventoryRecord(group: "London", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"), InventoryRecord(group: "NewYork", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaab") ]

struct ComputerEnhanced: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let name, id, serial,group: String
}

let result2: ComputerEnhanced = zip(computers, groupRecords)
    .map{ $0.0 


Release protocols and/or inheritance

For a) you can convert one of the arrays into a dictionary with serial as the key. b) I don’t really understand but maybe the same dictionary would work there as well

using zip won't work. That just combines items from 2 arrays into a new array of tuples, with no regard to their contents. The zip() function does not let you combine items based on having a shared value (like having the same serial number)

Maybe you need to clarify what you want with b), all items from each arrays or all merged items from the two arrays?

Create a common protocol (e.g. HasSerialNumber) between your different object types:
protocol HasSerialNumber {
    var serial: String {
        get
    }
}
struct Computer: Identifiable, Hashable, HasSerialNumber {
    let name, id, serial: String
}


struct InventoryRecord: Hashable, HasSerialNumber {
    let group, serial: String
}

You can then create arrays of objects that conform to HasSerialNumber, and write methods that will act on those objects/arrays:
var array: [HasSerialNumber] = [
    Computer(name: "Hal 9000", id: "12", serial: "ABCD"),
    Computer(name: "ENIAC", id: "1", serial: "EBCDIC"),
    InventoryRecord(group: "a", serial: "ABCD")
]

Or your code:
var computers: [HasSerialNumber] = [ Computer(name: "Mac1", id: "1", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"), Computer(name: "Mac2", id: "2", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaab") ]

var groupRecords: [HasSerialNumber] = [ InventoryRecord(group: "London", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"), InventoryRecord(group: "NewYork", serial: "aaaaaaaaaaab") ]

I'd suggest using a Dictionary of HasSerialNumber objects using their serial property as a key, and a value of [HasSerialNumber]. Then you could put all the objects with the same serial number into the same dictionary entry.

As Lorem Ipsum mentioned in their comment, you could also make your objects class objects rather than structs, and create a common base class and subclasses for your Computer and InventoryRecord objects. Your sample code uses structs, so I based my answer on that.

Thanks for the suggestions. To clarify a bit what I'm trying to achieve.
What I want to be able to do is to select the computer from the list - so have access to the name and serial number - but also have access to the group attribute. Ideally, so that I can navigate to different screens based off those 2 attributes.
For that reason, I was thinking that the simplest thing might be to be able to merge the two into a new struct array. Because the data could keep change I would need to be able to do this dynamically.

I'm not sure if creating a dictionary with the all the different objects contained will work, for my purpose but I will try it. Thanks.

Are you assuming that there would only be one Computer and one InventoryRecord with the same serial number?

Yes, definitely.

@boristheslug this is less of a SwiftUI issue based on your comments and more of a “relationship” issue with the serial number being the primary key. Research primary key and databases.
